# Convert an image array to a binarized image

Tags: python, arrays, image, binary

I have an Image array `Indice` which is like this:

```
array([[158,   0, 252, ..., 185, 186, 187],
   [254, 253, 252, ..., 188, 188, 189],
   [247, 249, 252, ..., 188, 187, 186],
   ..., 
   [176, 172, 168, ..., 204, 205, 205],
   [178, 175, 172, ..., 206, 205, 206],
   [180, 177, 174, ..., 206, 207, 207]], dtype=uint8)
```

I want to convert `Indice` to a binarized image (values between 0 and 1) with a threshehold near 0 (0.1 or 0.2). how can I do it in Python ?

Comment: use `opencv` : http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html

Comment: If I understand correctly, Can't you divide the entire array by 255?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.where` to binarize the data after converting it to the range from 0 to 1 by dividing by 255

```
threshold = 0.2
new_indice = np.where(Indice/255>=threshold, 1, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

If a boolean binary array is fine for you, you can simply use numpy's element-wise comparison:

```
new_indice = (Indice/255 > threshold)
```

In fact, for random test arrays this seemed to be slightly faster than the `np.where` solution. In case you need an integer binary array you can simply add a `1*` in front of the parentheses, but then the speed advantage seems to be gone.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this kind of task is by using [list comprehensions](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk).

In your case:

```
array([[1 if x>threshold else 0 for x in line] for line in Indice])
```

Where **threshold** would be set to the value you want.

Comment: His starting array is 8-bit integer, not float

Comment: It looks like he is using a numpy array.  Iterating over an array is generally not a good method.

Comment: @James Yes it right. What is a better way to do it ?